# An error upon using entity reference field with data created with view

Tags: views, 8, entities

Today I have faced with an error which shows up when I use an entity reference field with data created with view.
Namely, I need to output a list of cities with their countries and regions.
That is, for Moscow I need to output "Moscow *Moskow region, Russia*". And so on.

For example, there are cities from my view.

Капернаум *Израиль*
c. Радонеж *Московская область, Россия*
Таганрог *Ростовская область, Россия*

I managed to create a view with display "entity reference" and the preview shows it correctly.
But, when I'm trying to use this field on my insert/edit node form in autocomplete mode, for unknown reason only city name shows, without country and region name. Moreover, the showed city name is not plain text, but it is a link to a node where this sity is saved (see the screenshot).

[image: The city name is show without region and country]

Could you clarify me, why city is showed without country and region and with the link to the node ? Is it a bug ? Or am I mistaken somewhere creating the view ?

Comment: autocomplete fields typically only show you the entity label, not specific fields or content within the entity itself.

Comment: As I know, in the popup list all the data should be output. Whereas in the edit field after selection city name with nid in parentheses is showed.